# Why is coverage not 100% in this python-inquirer script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, command-line-interface, coverage.py

I have a simple method that receives a list of trades (descriptions and ids) and return the id of selected ones. If none is selected, you are asked to confirm that. I used python-inquirer to do that:

```py
# question.py
from typing import List, Tuple
import inquirer

def select_trades(trades: List[Tuple[str, int]]) -> List[int]:
    while True:
        selection = inquirer.prompt(
            [
                inquirer.Checkbox(
                    "trades",
                    message=(
                        "Select auction trades? "
                        "(press space to select and enter to finish)"
                    ),
                    choices=trades,
                )
            ]
        )["trades"]
        if len(selection) == 0:
            answer = inquirer.prompt(
                [
                    inquirer.List(
                        "",
                        message="No trade selected.\nDo you confirm?",
                        choices=["Yes", "No"],
                    )
                ]
            )[""]
            if answer == "Yes":
                return []
        else:
            break
    return selection
```

I made 2 test cases. One you select none, don't confirm, select none again and confirm. The other case you select the id 1:

```py
# test_question.py
from unittest.mock import patch

from question import select_trades

@patch(
    "inquirer.prompt",
    side_effect=[{"trades": []}, {"": "No"}, {"trades": []}, {"": "Yes"}],
)
def test_select_trades_empty(mock_inquirer_prompt) -> None:
    trades = [("trade 1", 0), ("trade 2", 1)]
    assert select_trades(trades) == []


@patch("inquirer.prompt", return_value={"trades": [1]})
def test_select_trades_some_selected(mock_inquirer_prompt) -> None:
    trades = [("trade 1", 0), ("trade 2", 1)]
    assert select_trades(trades) == [1]
```

For some reason, coverage is saying that the `break` like is not covered, but in the second test case, the `while True` breaks and return the expected value for the test. I don't see why it is not 100% covered in this case.

Comment: Is this an artifact of the coverage tool? Could you change the `else: break` into `else: return selection`?

Comment: `else return selection` goes to 100% the problem is, why it is not with current code? Maybe a bug in coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to Python optimization of jumps, making Coverage.py incapable of seeing this line is covered (https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/198).

Comment: The description in that issue makes clear that it's due to Python optimizing jumps to jumps with no option to disable the optimization. I don't think there's anything coverage.py can do about this.

Comment: Thanks Ned, I altered the answer to make it more specific.